# Does follow-post not notify when an edit that went through was suggested?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, notifications, follow-post

I've been testing/trying out the follow post feature.

In [this post](https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/55017/timeline), I was not notified of the edit. The edit was suggested and approved (not a direct edit). To be sure I checked my global inbox, and it's not there.

For the timeline of events: I've been following (and still am for troubleshooting purposes) since Sep 17. Edit was Sep 18, and was suggested not before, but after my following, as it includes my improvement suggestion (OP is unregistered, and they created another account to make the edit).

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not. I just checked the code, and currently only the post owner is notified on a suggested edit.

I don't remember there being a specific reason why it wasn't implemented. However, thinking the issues through, one could make the arguments that:

- It is not relevant to show suggested edits to users who have followed who do not have enough rep to evaluate it, so we might want to show it only to followers who are over that rep threshold.
- We want suggested edits to go through the review queue (or go to the post owner), and showing it to followers will bypass that.
- Followers shouldn’t just get special access to approve the edits just because they followed.

So while it is something that you could [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), in my opinion it is not a straightforward bug-by-omission.